# SED renaming with unknown amount of characters before a "

Tags: sed

I have a `file1` that has some PHP code in it. I need to find the following: `action="blahblah"` and replace it with `action="error.php"`. Problem is, I don't know how many characters are between the quotes in the original.

Here's what I have that doesn't work:

```
sed 's:action="^[^"]*":action="error.php":' <file1> file2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have you got the `^` start-of-line marker before the character class? Try it with:

```
sed 's:action="[^"]*":action="error.php":' <file1 > file2
```

Here's a transcript showing your version alongside that correction:

```
pax$ echo 'blah action="something" blah' | sed '
...$    s:action="^[^"]*":action="error.php":'
blah action="something" blah

pax$ echo 'blah action="something" blah' | sed '
...$    s:action="[^"]*":action="error.php":'
blah action="error.php" blah
```